# How to change ruby variable value every second?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have such problem: I want to show counter, which will be changing every second, so I need to change Ruby variable, which I will be using in jQuery.

**EDIT: I want to make counter, that will be the same for all users.**

I have counter.json.erb file:

```
 {
 "count": <%= @counter%>
 }
```

and action:

```
def counter
 @counter //here I need to change variable
 respond_to do |format|
 format.jsonr do
  render :json 
   end
 end
end
```

and I'm taking this varibale using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/counter.json', function(data) {
    alert(data.count);//alert just for testing
})
```

**EDIT: Suggested code:**

```
     var counter = 0
     $(document).ready(function(){
var myCounter = new flipCounter('counter', {value:counter});
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/counter.json', function(data) {
 myCounter.setValue(data.count);
})
});  

   setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/counter.json', function(data) {
 myCounter.setValue(data.count);
   }, 1000);
```

and I get error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input application.js:1
```

Maybe someone can suggest something ? Maybe other solution ?

Comment: Why do you need this counter in Ruby on your server? Would it be besser to do it on the client side using jQuery?

Comment: @Bjoernsen Maybe he wants it to be client independent ( as you surely know JavaScript can be easily hacked ), like for example some kind of security key changin every second.

Comment: @Bjoernsen, please look at updated question.

Comment: @freakish, please look at updated question, mayby you will understand it better.

Comment: Do you mean a visit counter, or a timer?

Comment: @Austin, timer. All users should see the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to actually "change the variable every second". It's much simpler than that:

1. Pick a start time (or end time) and store the value somewhere
2. At any time, take the current time
3. Calculate the difference between the two

Done. You can repeat this algorithm at any time and always get the current status of the timer.

Comment: deceze, one more thing - how to update value not ondocument load ?

Comment: "not ondocument load"? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean dynamically. With ajax request or how it should be done ?

Comment: You can do it exactly as described in my answer in Javascript too. The server communicates the start/end time to the page once. Then just loop in Javascript using `setInterval` to update a timer every x seconds.

Comment: I take data using jSon from erb.json file. I will show you my code, what I written and error what I get, Can you look at it ?